# Firebase : Serializing arrays is not supported

Tags: java, android

I am trying to put an object to my firebase database but I am getting the following error saying Array serialization is not supported and I should use Lists instead.

I am a newbie here please help me

Here is the DataPojo object I am trying to put into firebase

```
public class DataPojo {
private String msg1;
private String msg2;
private String msg3;
private String msg4;
private String msg5;
private String msg6;
private String msg7;
private String msg8;
private String msg9;
private String msg10;
private String msg11;
private String name;

public DataPojo(){}

public DataPojo(String msg1, String msg2, String msg3, String msg4, String msg5, String msg6, String msg7, String msg8, String msg9, String msg10, String msg11, String name) {
    this.msg1 = msg1;
    this.msg2 = msg2;
    this.msg3 = msg3;
    this.msg4 = msg4;
    this.msg5 = msg5;
    this.msg6 = msg6;
    this.msg7 = msg7;
    this.msg8 = msg8;
    this.msg9 = msg9;
    this.msg10 = msg10;
    this.msg11 = msg11;
    this.name = name;
}

public String getMsg9() {
    return msg9;
}

public void setMsg9(String msg9) {
    this.msg9 = msg9;
}

public String getMsg10() {
    return msg10;
}

public void setMsg10(String msg10) {
    this.msg10 = msg10;
}

public void setMsg11(String msg11) {
    this.msg11 = msg11;
}

public String getMsg11() {
    return msg11;
}

public String getMsg1() {
    return msg1;
}

public void setMsg1(String msg1) {
    this.msg1 = msg1;
}

public String getMsg2() {
    return msg2;
}

public void setMsg2(String msg2) {
    this.msg2 = msg2;
}

public String getMsg3() {
    return msg3;
}

public void setMsg3(String msg3) {
    this.msg3 = msg3;
}

public String getMsg4() {
    return msg4;
}

public void setMsg4(String msg4) {
    this.msg4 = msg4;
}

public String getMsg5() {
    return msg5;
}

public void setMsg5(String msg5) {
    this.msg5 = msg5;
}

public String getMsg6() {
    return msg6;
}

public void setMsg6(String msg6) {
    this.msg6 = msg6;
}

public String getMsg7() {
    return msg7;
}

public void setMsg7(String msg7) {
    this.msg7 = msg7;
}

public String getMsg8() {
    return msg8;
}

public void setMsg8(String msg8) {
    this.msg8 = msg8;
}

public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}

public String[] getMessages() {
    String[] messages = new String[11];
    messages[0] = msg1;
    messages[1] = msg2;
    messages[2] = msg3;
    messages[3] = msg4;
    messages[4] = msg5;
    messages[5] = msg6;
    messages[6] = msg7;
    messages[7] = msg8;
    messages[8] = msg9;
    messages[9] = msg10;
    messages[10] = msg11;
    return messages;
}
}
```

Why is it giving me that error? is it because of the getMessages() method? I do not have an array field declared though.

Comment: You have an array *property* declared, and why do you have so many individual fields anyway instead of just using an array or list?

Comment: Even thought it's just a temporary property? What's the workaround for this? And it's because I have to change them individually in my firebase database

Comment: There's no such thing as a "temporary property"--according to the JavaBeans standard, if there's a `getFoo()` method, you have a `foo` property.

Comment: Ok then, genius. So what do I do?

Comment: Use a List instead, like it says. `ArrayList<String> messages = new ArrayList<>()`.